# How to fetch string?

Tags: flutter

I have code like this:

```
  Future<http.Response> makeRequest() async {
    return await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  }
```

my "url" is a string, and it is working. From the internet i got string like "10" or "125", but when i use this method in my project and im converting it to string it only writes me an error:

> Instance of 'Future Response'

, how can i take my string from the internet?

this is my url:
https://apialgorytm20210606150610.azurewebsites.net/algorytm/5w5

Answer (score 0):

```
     Future  makeRequest() async {
    var res= await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    
       If(res.statusCode==200){
print(res.body);
return res.body;}else{return null;}
      }
```

now use the above function

var data=makeRequest();

print(data);

Comment: sadly i still get that error, i have:
string result;
result = makeRequest().toString();
i take my result in "bad" way? result shuld have only "10" in it

Comment: the must be in JSON format if you are using an HTTP requests.

Comment: print (res.body) will tell  about your data format.   by removing the return statement

Comment: this is my url:

https://apialgorytm20210606150610.azurewebsites.net/algorytm/5w5

Comment: i updated answer use this is working fine

Comment: in my console i can see "I/flutter (30112): 20" it is good result it is working, but how i can take this value and give it to eany string? eany variable? it almost working

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<String> getObjectFromAPI() async {
   var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('www.myAPI.com/getData'),); //1
   if (response.statusCode == 200) { //2
     return(jsonDecode(response.body)["yourObjectHere"]); //3
   } else {
     return 'error';
   }
 }
```

Here you go.
Put your API url in line 1.
Line 2 checks if you receive a 200OK return or some kind of error code. Line 3 prints the decoded JSON response from the API, and you can enter the specific object you want to fetch as well

Comment: ymm, i am veary close to my solution i did get block of stuff in my console, where is "Reciver" and there my string, do you know how to return this string or where i can parse it to my global variable?

Comment: @Maciek in order to assign this function to a variable you would call ````String dataFromAPI = await getObjectFromAPI();````

Comment: 1. [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.
2. i do not know what kind of "yourObjectHere" i shuld put there :c
3. see my link i only take from there a specific number, not entire big json

Comment: print ````response.body```` and post it here (as long as it doesn't contain sensitive data) so I know what datatype you are working with in the API. I have no code that should result in an int

Comment: how to print response.body? what shuld i do?